# Problem with resolution of exported image

Tags: export, geographics

I want to make a map (of Germany) with certain positions marked. This is just a MWE, in fact there are much more positions. What I did:

```
   positions = {{47.5`, 11.08`}, {47.57`, 8.03`}, {47.6`, 
   8.13`}, {47.65`, 7.6`}, {47.65`, 7.78`}, {47.66`, 9.48`}, {47.7`, 
   10.32`}, {47.73`, 12.1`}, {47.77`, 9.72`}, {47.77`, 11.62`}}
```

and

```
marker = Graphics[{Blue, PointSize[0.4], Point[{0, 0}]}];
```

then (this - Entity - is keyed in manually because of the complicated structure of the Entity in this command when done via copy and paste)

```
    map = GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling["StreetMap"], 
            Polygon[Entity["Country","Germany"]],
            GeoZoomLevel -> 9,
            GeoMarker[positions, marker]
            }, 
            GeoBackground -> None, ImageSize -> 2000]
```

If I do so the map looks fine:

[image]

If I export the image:

```
Export["germany-04.JPG", map, "JPG"];
```

and re-import the image it is much more coarse. I tried with something like

```
Export["germany-04.JPG", map, "JPG", ImageResolution-> 300];
```

and explicit ImageSize, but I never get close to the the original resolution (same with export formats like SVG, EPS, PNG. 
If I copy the map (as graphics) and try to import in Photoshop....  Mathematica crashes (??).

My system: MacOS 10.13.5, Mathematica 11.3.0, my goal is to get an exported image good for print.

[image]

Comment: JPEG ([`"JPG"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JPEG.html)) image files has lossy compression, and *Mathematica* uses a `"CompressionLevel"` of `0.25` by default.

Comment: @rhermans: JPG was just an example here - same problems with SVG, WMF, PNG etc. Picture dimensions are approx. 2000x2700, so this is too few to get the names of towns readable in a "pixel-environment". It seems that PDF is much better there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it as pdf, then open in Acrobat and the resolution seems to be preserved.

Export["germany-04.pdf", map, "PDF"];

The pdf file is about 40 MB, so that may explain the instability when trying to copy/paste.

[image]